# Java regex pattern not working as mentioned

Tags: java, regex

I want to allow alpha numeric values and only a few special characters in my string.

regex **`[a-zA-Z0-9[@#%&\\s]]`**

When I tried with Matcher.find(), it's saying true, even if I used other special characters in the string.  Ex : **`welcome123^456`**.  It should get false (not-matched).

When I used String.matches(), it's saying false, even for the correct pattern.  Ex: **`welcomeAA123@`**.  Its supposed to get true. But I am getting false.

Following are the only 5 special chars I wish to allow along with Alpha+numeric.
@ # $ % &

For Ex: 
welcome123#  - should get true 
welcome123$  - should get true 
welcome123_  - should get false (because underscore is not allowed.)
welcome$@  - should get true 
1234$@  - should get true

Comment: What are the "few special characters" that you mention? Do they include open and close square brackets (`[` and `]`)?

Comment: To start off. You are looking for only 1 character / digit / symbol. So matches() fails. use `[a-zA-Z0-9[@#%&\s]]+"`. Also, why 2 `[`s?

Comment: Please show us an example of what you tried, in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the usage of nested square brackets, which gives you a union character class (See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)). That is to say, `[a-zA-Z0-9[@#%&\s]]` matches *either* a `String` with upper and lower case alphanumeric characters, *or* a `String` containing just the special characters listed.

Your pattern also matches a single character of the class defined - you need to use something like `+` to match one Strings of more than one character in length.

If you want to include square brackets in your allowed characters you should escape them, or if not then you should not nest your character classes

```
"welcomeAA123@".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9@#%&\\s\\[\\]]+") //true
"welcome123^456".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9@#%&\\s\\[\\]]+") //false
"welcomeAA123@".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9@#%&\\s]+") //true
"welcome123^456".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9@#%&\\s]+") //false
"welcomeAA123[@]".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9@#%&\\s\\[\\]]+") //true
"welcomeAA123[@]".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9@#%&\\s]+") //false
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quantifier and anchors:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9[@#%&\\s\\]]+$
```

Also: matches return true if the whole string matches the given pattern. find tries to find a substring that matches the pattern.